# Gmaps throwing undefined exception

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having 2 pages in an MVC 4 application in both of which I am using Gmaps.js to load google maps.

The strange issue is which even page among these two pages I made as start page loads the following code correctly, while when I navigate to the other map = new GMaps throws exception stating GMaps is undefined.

```
map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: 28.6066700,
    lng: 77.1490000,
    zoom: defaultZoomLevel,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style: 'LARGE',
        position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    minZoom: defaultZoomLevel,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
});
```

Can't I use Gmaps at two places, ideally I don't think so, but I am not able to figure out the reason of this behavior.

Comment: when Gmaps is undefined the library obviously isn't loaded. You may use GMaps to create as much maps as you want.

Comment: both the pages have same set of libraries, which ever page i made as start page works fine, while the other throws the error.